# MySQL returning incorrect results by INT Column

Tags: mysql, sql

When running the following query:

```
SELECT id,name,verified FROM servers WHERE verified=1 AND enabled=1 AND suspended=0 AND name LIKE '%.net%' || ip LIKE '%.net%' ORDER BY score DESC
```

MySQL is returning incorrect results. Here is the result of that input:

```
+----+-------------------+----------+
| ID |       name        | verified |
+----+-------------------+----------+
| 34 | BlockedUp         |        1 |
|  8 | aliacraft         |        1 |
| 27 | Limitless MC      |        1 |
| 31 | OPCraft           |        1 |
| 33 | LoneWolves Prison |        1 |
| 47 | purpleprison.net  |        0 |
+----+-------------------+----------+
```

What could be the reason for this? The last row does obviously not match the requirement of verified=1.

Comment: You need to group the conditions in the Where condition

Comment: @james The OR '%.net%' is independent of the other conditions unless you have them wrapped in ()'s  you're query says (enabled=1 and suspended = 0 and name like.net) or (ip like '%.net%')  What's the IP of ID 47?  I'm guessing it has .net in it.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've solved the problem now with Abhik's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move

```
AND name LIKE '%.net%' || ip LIKE '%.net%'
```

in braces as

```
AND ( name LIKE '%.net%' or ip LIKE '%.net%' )
```